# How to filter by key, find by date range, and then aggregate by week in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection named `MyCollection` which consists of documents that look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58085384e4b0f70605461e3f"), 
    "uid" : "fa1aeafc-18db-41a5-8ee5-ac0c32428fe1",
    "Key1" : "Value1"  
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-08-23T17:58:20.000+0000"), 
}
```

Some of the documents have `Key1`, while others have `Key2` or `Key3`.

Now, I wish to do the following:-

1. Get only those documents that have `Key1` or `Key2`.
2. From the resulting set of documents above, get only those documents which are in the `timeStamp` range `Date(2016, 08, 01)` to `Date(2016, 08, 31)`.
3. For the resulting set of documents above, aggregate them by week.

How do I write a mongo query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the aggregation framework, the above steps can be done with the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline steps as follows:

```
var start = new Date(2016, 7, 1), // months are zero-based indexes i.e Aug month index is 7
    end = new Date(2016, 7, 30); // August month ends on the 30th

db.collection.aggregate([
    { /* filter steps 1 & 2 */
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                { "Key1": { "$exists": true } },
                { "Key2": { "$exists": true } }
            ],
            "timeStamp": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },
    { /* group by week */ 
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "$week": "$timeStamp" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "uids": { "$push": "$uid" }
        }
    }
])
```

In the above, the date range is created using the **[`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** constructor where months are zero-based indexes. The **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** operator is used to determine the existence of a key and use the **[`$week`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/#exp._S_week)** date aggregate operator to get the week number in a date between 0 (the partial week that precedes the first Sunday of the year) and 53 (leap year).

For week numbers starting at 1 with the week (Monday through Sunday) that contains the year's first Thursday, MongoDB 3.4 and newer provided the **[`$isoweek`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isoWeek/#exp._S_isoWeek)** operator for use.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
db.collection.find(
{$or:[{"key1":{$exists:true}},{"key2":{$exists:true}}],
timeStamp: {$gte: Date(2016, 08, 01), $lte:Date(2016, 08, 31)}
})
```

above query fulfilled your 1 and 2 condition.What is your 3rd condition I do not understand fully, please elaborate.